# Programming practices - using helper method to hide object

Tags: javascript, oop, tdd, google-closure-library

I was reading through the code segment of [closure library](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/dom/dom.js), I saw this code fragment there:

```
/**
 * Gets the document object being used by the dom library.
 * @return {!Document} Document object.
 */
goog.dom.getDocument = function() {
  return document;
};
```

Why we have wrapped the document reference in the getter method? isn't document is a global object?

Comment: So you can mock it out (replace the method) for tests and provide a fake document. Or, any time, just splitting the underlying implementation.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I don't get it, even then the method would return the modified value not the correct one, how its defensive?

Comment: oops.. My bad. I overlooked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two logical reasons, both involving the Closure Compiler:

1. **Type checking** - When calling this function, the Closure Compiler will know that the return type is of type [`Document`](http://krook.org/jsdom/Document.html) and that it is never null. Presumably Google Closure developers could have hard-coded this into the Closure Compiler, but by being explicit they avoid adding special cases to the Closure Compiler for properties that exist on the global object.
2. **Minification** - When that function goes through [`ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3), `goog.dom.getDocument` can get minified to something like `a.b.c`. The Closure Compiler cannot rename `document` because it has no control over the variable name on the global object, but it can certainly rename functions that *reference* `document` to give you smaller source code.

Comment: I don't think that you get my question, I am asking why we needed function in the first place, what your are saying is that function will be minified.

Comment: Right, because you can't minify `document`. You can only minify a _reference_ to `document`, which this function provides.

Comment: So, you meant to say that the keyword "document" would be skipped altogether from the compressed code?

Comment: Correct. Google Closure has no control over what the browser calls the `document` variable. If the compiled code resulted in the `document` property being renamed to `foo`, the value of that `foo` property would be undefined because the browser would still be setting a property called `document` on the global object.

Comment: The same would be true for any other property the browser provides for you on the global object. In order to minify those properties, you first need to create a function that references it. Then you can minify the references.

Comment: Seems weird to me, code structure which depends upon the underlying technology.

Comment: Such is life with web frameworks, I suppose. All front end web technologies are confined to the [minimum common] boundaries exposed by the browsers upon which they run. Server-side frameworks, such as Rails, Servlets and ASP.NET, are highly opinionated in getting you to your write your code using specific classes and interfaces built on top of their implementations of handing HTTP requests. You trade freedom for efficiency - or so the frameworks claim.